# How do I validate a multiline column of SharePoint whether it is empty or not

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have a multi line column named "Business Justification". I have to validate it to show whether it is empty or not.

```
 if($('nobr:contains("Business Justification")').closest('tr').find('.ms-rtestate-write').val()== "")
         { 

            alert('provide business justification');
            return false;}
```

I used the above code but this gives the alert message even if value is given

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
var content=$("nobr:contains('Field Name')").parent().parent().parent().find("div.ms-inputBox div.ms-rtestate-write").text()
if (content.trim() == "")  
{ 
     alert("empty");
}
```

Replace the 'Field Name' token with column display name

Comment: the if condition doesnt work ......the  value is still saved  when the textbox in empty

Comment: Please share the MLT type- Enhanced rich or rich text box in SharePoint

Comment: its enhanced rich text

Comment: Try to log the value. There could be some hidden html tags in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

**Please try using the below code instead**

```
if($(".ms-rtestate-write[id^='Business_x0020_Justification']")[0].innerHTML=="<p>​</p>")
{
     alert('provide business justification');
                return false;
}
else 
     return true;
```

try and feedback

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score -1):

Try to make Business Justification mandatory.

http://dhirendrayadav.com/2010/06/make-existing-custom-column-required-in.html